# Is there a way to make videoview not the default view?

Tags: java, android, video, layout, android-videoview

The question may be confusing so let me outline it.

When I load an activity from a button click, this activity loads first at the bottom of the activity and not right at the top where it's meant to. Now just for context in my design the video view is part of a 'videos' section that is the last element loaded at the bottom of the activity.

I have tried messing with a few things like removing the video view and setting different anchor views. But ultimately the only way I have managed to fix this issue so far is by getting rid of the video view.

I will attach videos of the issue i'm seeing both without the video view and the video view.

If anyone can help i'd appreciate it.

Here is a link to the layout without the video view (Class this as the working example):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uhswtYUrJYnC22mlsdJzmRJqNua9mUrw/view?usp=sharing

Here's a link to the layout with the video view:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1unHp-7GULO_TEdg6KHNjAoIOW6X-N2Rs/view?usp=sharing

I will also for added context add the XML and the java for the video view part:

**XML file:**

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/videos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Videos"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <VideoView
                    android:id="@+id/videoview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </FrameLayout>
            
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Code:**

```
VideoView videoView;
private Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.company_solo_page);
    businessesList = new ArrayList<>();
    business_name = findViewById(R.id.bus_name);
    business_logo = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    bdesc = findViewById(R.id.bdesc);
    website = findViewById(R.id.website);
    social = findViewById(R.id.socialmedia);
    careers = findViewById(R.id.careers);
    contact = findViewById(R.id.contact);
    videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    videoView.setVideoPath(getIntent().getStringExtra("videos"));
    videoView.start();
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a handler and runnable you can delay the execution of videoView.start() function call